# Using one connection for Context object in EF

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, connection, sql-server-profiler

How can I use same connection for two Query in EF, for example I wrote this code in MVC controller:

```
    DataLayer.Context context = new DataLayer.Context();

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public int TodayVisits()
    {
        return Repository.VisitsRepository.TodayVisits(context);
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public int LastMonthVisits()
    {
        return Repository.VisitsRepository.LastMonthVisits(context);
    }
```

I'm checking output T-SQL with an application and it shows me that connection 2 time was opened.

Comment: Are these two functions executed in the same MVC  action ? How do you call them ?

Comment: TodayVisits and LastMonthVisits are actions in a same controller and I have a context object in this controller and I named it context

Answer (score 2):

For each request from your browser the a [controller instance will be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463893/is-there-a-new-controller-instance-for-each-request).. So it will create new context for each request as well. 
And read this too, [What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET MVC page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webform).

Further more creating an instance of DbContext for each request is the [common practice for entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260665/mvc-4-ef-4-3-managing-context-during-the-lifecycle-of-an-application-request).

**Edit..**
If you need to handle the connection you need to pass the connection to the DbContext constructor and set `contextOwnsConnection`=false.  See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696604%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and try it..
Read more here..[DbContext won't keep connection open for re-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752491/entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-wont-keep-connection-open-for-re-use)

Comment: As you see I have 2 method that are ChildActionOnly. I want to use once opened connection in each request, I call these actions in same request but I monitored two opened connections.